# Is there anyway for my python script to automatically get access token for working in Dropbox API

Tags: python, dropbox-api

I am trying to build an python application for my server to run 24 hours and overwrite a file in dropbox every minute. When I built this application it stopped working after an hours for new token. I can't awake 24 hour to add new token every token. I just want a way that help me in doing setup of this. With dropbox there is no option to remove short length expire from token. Please keep it simple to underatnd easily dropbox documentation is hard for me to understand.

I just want a solution for this problem. I tried refresh token but it also required user interaction so no use.

Comment: One way to handle this is to use an "app token" instead of an "access token." App tokens do not expire, so you only need to obtain one once and then you can use it indefinitely

Answer (score 0):

Using refresh tokens is the right solution here. Just like with Dropbox access tokens, manual user interaction is required initially to get a Dropbox refresh token, but once the app has a refresh token it can store and re-use it repeatedly without further manual user interaction.

For reference, Dropbox is in the process of switching to only issuing short-lived access tokens (and optional refresh tokens) instead of long-lived access tokens. You can find [more information on this migration here](https://dropbox.tech/developers/migrating-app-permissions-and-access-tokens).

Apps can still get long-term access by requesting "offline" access though, in which case the app receives a "refresh token" that can be used to retrieve new short-lived access tokens as needed, without further manual user intervention. You can find more information in the [OAuth Guide](https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide) and [authorization documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization).

You can find [examples of using the OAuth app authorization flow in the Dropbox Python SDK here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/tree/main/example/oauth).